# Can you get User SID of the members in a Conference Channel?

Tags: twilio, twilio-conversations

I am building an application that will (1) create a conversation (chat), (2) create two users, then add the two users to the conversation. This part is working.

At a future time, given the Conversation SID (CHXXX...), I would like to remove the Users and the conversation. I can get a list of the conversation participants, but this includes a Member SID (MBXXX...) not the User SID (USXXX...). I believe I need the User SID to remove the user, not the Member SID.

I may be missing the obvious on how to cross-reference the conversation members to their respective users.

Thanks.

> I just realized I was overthinking this issue. When creating the participant, I can create a participant with a unique "identity" and then use that identity to give the user a "friendly name." The friendly name is displayed in the conversation. Then, when I tear down the conversation, I can directly delete the users using their "identity," there is no need to get their actual UserSid.

Answer (score 0):

Specific to, "At a future time" - could you leverage timers?

[Conversation Timers](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/states-timers)

> With Twilio Conversations' states and timers features, you can manage,
> store, and archive your application's Conversations.
>
> By using these features, your Conversations participants can focus on
> active (ongoing) Conversations. You can also close out old or inactive
> Conversations to make sure you're not exceeding the
> Participants-per-Conversation limit.

Also:

[List Conversation Participants Example and Delete Conversation Participants Example](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/conversation-participant-resource)

Comment: See my addition to the original question. I used the "identity" attribute of the participant and user.

Answer (score 0):

When you [add the participant to the conversation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/conversation-participant-resource#add-a-conversation-participant-sms), you will receive the `sid` in the response, so you could save that to use when you [delete the participant from the conversation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/conversation-participant-resource#delete-a-conversationparticipant-resource) later.

Alternatively, if you are stuck with just user and conversation SIDs, you can look up  the participant SID using the two SIDs you have and the [User Conversation resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/user-conversation-resource#fetch-a-specific-conversation).

Comment: See my addition to the original question. I used the "identity" attribute of the participant and user.

Comment: Ah, cool. You can add this as an answer too, if you like?

Answer (score 0):

I just realized I was overthinking this issue. When creating the participant, I can create a participant with a unique "identity" and then use that identity to give the user a "friendly name." The friendly name is displayed in the conversation. Then, when I tear down the conversation, I can directly delete the users using their "identity," there is no need to get their actual UserSid.